# ASP.NET Server Control - Reuse Type/Objects in Web References

Tags: visual-studio-2008, custom-server-controls

I was wondering if it's possible to reuse objects in web references in an ASP.NET Server control? (basically keeping the same web reference name)

I have a few web services (.asmx) that I want to group with the same web reference name, however when I consume them using the same name they append a 1 at the end and with all object names.

Right Click - Add Web Reference
Enter URL of asmx
Type "MyServices" in for Web Reference Name

Repeat, Add Web Reference
Type "MyServices" in for Web Reference Name
And it adds it as "MyServices1" rather than grouping and reusing the same objects.

This only appears to do this on ASP.NET Server Controls - any other project that I have ever created, standard c# console application, asp.net web application all group the objects and web reference names together.

Am I missing a patch, upgrade, or is this just not possible with a Server Control?

Just for a little background, I'm creating a control that I can drop into projects based on a single dll.

I'm able to group the services in a test project if it's a web application, however they do not group in the Server Control project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Jamey

An example is located here:

[image: http://imgur.com/6tqvQ.jpg]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And, in terms of code - you could use an alias for the namespace if you want to bring them all under 1 head. I am sorry, if I have not understood the question completely.

Comment: Hi - I guess I wasn't too clear on what I was trying to do.  I'm not trying to join the two asmx files on the service end, I'm trying to join them as under the same Web Reference Name under the Web Reference folder when I consume them.  I'm not able to do this with an ASP.NET Service Control application.

Comment: I still seem to be having this issue.  I'm trying to consume multiple web services (.asmx) that reside on the server at the same project into one "Web Reference Name" in the new Web Application.  With an ASP.NET Web Application it always appends a 1 to the imported namespace if it exists previously... hmm... ASP.NET WebSite Projects group them as expected.  I've added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

There's only meant to be one WSDL per web reference, which means only one .ASMX per web reference.

In order to share types between proxies to multiple .ASMX files, you need to use the command-line tool WSDL.EXE:

```
WSDL /shareTypes http://localhost/service1.asmx?wsdl http://localhost/service2.asmx?wsdl ...
```

This will produce a single code file, and will produce one type per combination of XML namespace, name and wire signature.

Comment: I'm able to consume multiple services and give them the same Web Reference Name on just about every project except a ASP.NET Server Control project.  I'm trying to consume them as the same web reference name so that I can reference them all as say - com.example.services, rather different web service names.  Each consumed web service should come in with it's own discomap and wsdl under that web reference name - but I can't seem to get this to work correctly under ASP.NET Serivce Controls.  I've added a screenshot above of what I'm trying to do.  I hope it makes more sense.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: It does sound more like a bug than anything else.